# Facebook not accepting apps for the Listen action

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, listen

Facebook says it's not accepting any new submission for the Listen action. I need to use this feature for a iOS app. Is there a time frame as to when Facebook will start accepting new submissions using this feature?

Alternatively, does this restriction only apply to apps being developed on the Facebook platform? So can I use it in my iOS app presently since I don't have to submit to Facebook before launch? Thanks.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/music.listens/

Comment: _Any_ app that wants to publish any kind of Open Graph actions _has_ to be submitted for approval before those actions can be used by the public (before approval, only developers and testers of the app can use them, and they will be visible only to those as well) – so I don’t understand what you mean by using it in your app “presently” before launch, what good would that do you …?

Comment: And if you want anything “official” on whether or not they will accept new submissions for that action any time soon, you’d have to ask Facebook themselves (or hope that an FB employee reading this here can give you any info) – but I doubt it, as far as I understand it they have made that feature available only to a very limited selection of “big players” (such as Spotify) as of now, that they have certain kinds of partnerships with.

Comment: I didn't realize any app on any platform using Open Graph actions had to be submitted to Facebook before launch. Thanks a lot for your input.

I'll see if there is a way to get in touch with Facebook developers about this issue and see if we can possible negotiate something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got an explanation from a Developer Support Engineer at Facebook :

"The music.listen action is currently whitelisted for selected partners. We aren't accepting requests to be whitelisted at this time. If/when we release music.listen we'll announce it on our blog."

Hope it helps.